# How to install a washing machine outlet?

Tags: washing-machine

I moved into a new apartment and I encountered a washing machine outlet that I have not seen before.

It feels like I will need some sort of adapter to connect the plane hose going from my washing machine to the drain.

Any help on how to connect my washing machine to the drain would be appreciated.

Picture of my outlet:

[image]

Comment: That's not in the US, but isn't it as simple as removing the red plug and sliding the hose over the nipple?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, a universal washing machine hose with clamps should work.  Pull the red plug out, slide a stainless steel compression ring over the hose, push the hose over the barbed connection and tighten the clamp/ring about 1/2" from the end so it's centered over the barbs.

I went to the Dallmer website but they didn't indicate any particular hose for connection, nor sell any.